# Evaluate HTML injected with v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How would one go about injecting raw HTML with Vue when that HTML contains Vue markup that needs to be evaluated?

For example, this could be used to render HTML when it comes from a variable:

```html
<p v-html="markup"></p>
```

```js
{
    computed: {
        markup() {
            return 'Hello <em>World</em>!';
        },
    },
}
```

This will work nicely, but what if the `markup` computed property also included a custom Vue component?

```
return 'Hello <em>World</em>! My name is <my-name></my-name>!';
```

In this case `<my-name></my-name>` will not be evaluated unfortunately and just rendered as-is.

How do I go about having it "Vue-fied" and also how does scope work in that case?

Comment: Do you need totally generic contents or is it bounded in some way? The `:is` attribute could be useful. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is

Comment: @bernie Yes, totally generic. Basically a mixture of HTML including any valid Vue markup provided by a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I read the docs thoroughly, turns out it's not really possible "out-of-the-box" as it's somewhat of an anti-pattern.

The problem I am trying to fix however demands it as I want to be able to inject custom components in an arbitrary places in translated text.

I ended up using [Custom Directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

The only limitation here is that if you want to pass a property, say `name` from the context of where you're including the directive, you must reference it via `$parent`.

```js
return 'Hello <em>World</em>! My name is <my-name :name="$parent.name"></my-name>!';
```

Usage will be:

```html
<p v-markup="markup"></p>
```

When rendered, the above will be identical to doing this:

```html
<p>
    Hello <em>World</em>! My name is <my-name :name="name"></my-name>!
</p>
```

[Checkout this Gist](https://gist.github.com/TonyBogdanov/07ae0c1603b75eeb46563b81e7852bdd)